# How to delete specific files?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, log-files

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. I have a directory with million of files named like this

```
master-stdout.log.20210801.024908
master-stdout.log.20210801.025524
master-stdout.log.20210801.064355
```

How can I delete all of master-stdout.log files?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `rm master-stdout.log.*` (remember the `*`)

Comment: doesn't work it gives error: /bin/rm: Argument list too long

Answer (score 1):

If you get `Argument list too long` there is to many files, but there is workarounds...

```sh
find . -name "master-stdout.log.*" -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11289567/2716218